# Recommended way of html5 forms for display (readonly) only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html

I tried looking this up, but did't find any leads...

What is the recommended way of building forms for display data only?

Normally you  have for editing:

```
<form ... >
 <label>My label <input type='text'></label>
 <input type='submit'>
<form>
```

But now, i want the same form but just not for editing (typical read-only views for database webapps).

The *label* tag seems to be hooked up with input tags, so your not supposed to use this? And what if you used *fieldset* tag in your forms, how do you display these?

Whats the correct approach, something like this:?

```
<div class='form'>
   <div class='label'>My Label<div class='value'>my value</div></div>
</div>
```

Are you supposed to wrap everything in div tags and spans?

**From Rails perspective**

There is DRY, and this seems a bit double, since your edit forms -in general- has the same data as the 'view', but yet you set them up separate (unlike new / edit)? Curious how you guys keep your view and _edit forms in-sync.

Thanks!

Comment: How about using the disabled property on input tags?

Comment: yeah i thought of that! but then i got doubted if your not putting unnecessary load on the server, for going through all the 'form' stuff....seems like the 'easy' way, but not the recommended way ;-)

Comment: I don't think you should be worried about performance at such a level. The question is much more what you think looks better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **readonly** attribute in your text fields,

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="myValue">
```

Comment: But don't forget to close your input tags=>  />